# Cause of "class, interface, or enum expected" Java syntax error?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax-error

I get the error "class, interface, or enum expected" from this line.

```
image RenderList[] = new image[99];
```

Where image is a class I made. I read a number of tutorials/threads asking how to make an array of objects, and they all agreed with that line. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @pst: that should be an answer methinks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this works:

```
package cruft;

public class Image {

    private String name;

    public Image(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Image [] images = new Image[args.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String name : args) {
            images[i++] = new Image(name);            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Image");
        sb.append("{name='").append(name).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the line causing the error, then it is simply that `image` does not resolve as a type (e.g. a class). The javacc compiler should also have emitted a following line with a "^" that indicates exactly which part of that statement is invalid. (Remember to include the *full* compiler error in the post.)

Make sure `image` is what the class is *really* called (the class should likely be called `Image` per the Java naming conventions) and that any required imports are used if the "image" class is in a different namespace. It could also simply be that the compiler can't find the corresponding "image" class if it is not looking at the correct location for the the JAR/".class"/".java" files.

Providing more context (e.g. the definition of the "image" class and the namespace both sections of code are in) would lead to a definitive problem identification and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Java, the easiest approach is to make sure all of the classes for a particular program are in the same directory. Perhaps you created the class "image" in another directory. When the compiler can't find it, you will simply get the sort of error you encountered. This was a common error among my students.

As several respondents pointed out, remember to give class names an initial caps, Image. The compiler doesn't care but it's a universal convention among Java programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parentheses as well as brackets.
`image RenderList[] = new image()[99];`
That should work.